# python pillow convert('1') не могу переобрвзовать в массив numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pillow, cv2

мне нужно преобразовать видео покадрово, в фильтр библиотеки pillow - convert('1'), я использую модуль cv2, беру каждый фрейм, переобразовываю его из массива numpy в изображение для pillow,применяю фильтры, и переобразовываю обратно в массив numpy. проблема в том, что при использовании фильтра convert('1') массив состоит из False,но если использовать другие фильтры, все работает как часы.

```
im_2 = im.convert('L') #переобразование в ч\б
```

выводит обычный хороший массив:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

но если применить фильтр convert('1'):

```
im_2 = im.convert('1') #нужный мне фильтр
```

выводит:

```
[[False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 ...
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]]
```

что с этим делать? :(

Comment: Что такое im? И вообще покажите минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: во-первых, "L" - это не черно-белое изображение, а grayscale (оттенки серого). во-вторых, все правильно у вас выводится. для режима L записывается значение яркости (от 0 до 255), а для черно-белого режима "1" - булево значение (есть белый цвет или нет), то есть True или False. Так что вас не устраивает?